# Main application window and a dialog interaction in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, dialog

Good day!

Have a problem: main window (MyApp for example) works in background (behind all other windows or in tray), not necessary to show it without need. After some period of time some reminding StayOnTop dialog appears (having parent = 0, to be not tied to main window) and asks for some user interactions. After dialog closes I’d like to keep an application window user currently working with active, and user continue do his job not switching to MyApp. However, instead of above behaviour, main MyApp window appears and user forces to switch back to his window (job) – inconvenient.

How to prevent MyApp main window appearing after closing the dialog? Need to install some event filter or access OS API? Problem exists in Mac, Windows, Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try invoking hide method after dialog call? Other possibility - try setting this:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop to `Qt::Popup`.

Comment: Qt::Popup does not work as it makes dialog modal and shows main window immediately.  Will try to hide the dialog.

Comment: Hiding also leads to main window appearing, seems that guy was right: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/8495/#49421

Answer (score 0):

You could try to re-implement the main window's `showEvent` and ignore that event, in case other windows are visible.

```
void main_window::showEvent( QShowEvent* e )
{
    if( /*one or more of its children are visible */ )
    {
        // nothing to do
    }
    else
    {
        QMainWindow::showEvent( e );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought about this, just need to check if main window gets show event after closing the dialog. But Your condition will not work as the dialog will be closed before main window gets show event. Need to think about other condition.

However will check both proposed variants.

Comment: The condition refers to the _job-windows_ you mentioned. If they are `!isHidden()`, the main window should stay hidden. You know what I mean?

Comment: No, main window should stay hidden after dialog closes. Never mind, that does not work anyway as void MyWindow::showEvent( QShowEvent * event ) never gets control, I tried following: `void MyWindow::showEvent( QShowEvent * event ) { if(!event->spontaneous()) QMainWindow::showEvent(event); else event->ignore(); } `

Comment: That was problem of window manager: KDE or Mac. Works fine in Gnome or Windows.